# Solving system of linear equations with unknowns in both the left and right hand side.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to solve linear system of the kind: $Lx=Ry$, where $L$ and $R$ are square matrices and $x$ and $y$ are vectors both with knowns and unknowns. The situation is so that for every unknown $x$ the corresponding $y$ is known and vice versa. The system has unique solution for sure.
I know that I can solve this system with rearrangement, so that all unknowns are in left hand side and the knowns go to the right hand side. The problem is that I don't want to mess columns of $L$ with those of $R$.
Could I use some matrix factorization to transform the system to this form: $Cx=y$. I was thinking of using QR factorization of both $L$ and $R$ but I don't know how efficient it is going to be.

The best solution I can think of (without rearrangement) is to find the QR factorization of $R$ and to use it to find $R^{-1}$ and to left multiply the system by $R^{-1}$. This way I'll end up with the desired form $[R^{-1}L]x = y$, which I know how to solve separately for $x$ and $y$, though this left product matrix could be very messy and it could even be more inefficient than the rearrangement approach.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking is possible. The fact is, a solution is going to have to look like $z=$ stuff, where "stuff" includes some formula with $L$ and $R$ in it. Your matrix factorization idea is going to mess $L$ and $R$! Do you know which components of $x$ and $y$ are known and which are unknown?

Comment: can you post us your system?

Comment: Excuse me for not giving the system, but it is very large and I am seeking numerical solution. Nevertheless the matrices $L$ and $R$ are square and nonsingular. The biggest problem is that those matrices are with very different magnitudes, so messing their columns is not a preferable option. That is why I am trying to find a way to solve the system without messing $L$ and $R$, but it really seems impossible. And to the comment of Adrian, yes I know which of x and y components are the knowns.

Comment: Can't you rescale $y$ so that the orders of magnitudes in $L$ and $R$ match better ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes scaling gives good results!